# True/false? Let $v,w\in\mathbb{R}^n,n\in\mathbb{N},n\geq 2$. We have that $\left\langle v-w,v+w\right\rangle=\left\|v\right\|^2-\left\|w\right\|^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> True/false? Let $v,w\in\mathbb{R}^n,n\in\mathbb{N},n\geq 2$. We have
>   that $\left\langle
> v-w,v+w\right\rangle=\left\|v\right\|^2-\left\|w\right\|^2$

The statement should be true because

$$\left \langle v-w,v+w \right \rangle=\left \| v-w \right \|\cdot\left \| v+w \right \|=(v-w)(v+w)= \left \| v \right \|^2+vw-vw-\left \| w \right \|^2= \left \| v \right \|^2-\left \| w^2 \right \|$$

Is it good?

But what seems critical is this $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, does it have any bad influences here? I wouldn't know why it should.

Comment: The statement is true, but your reasoning is flawed. 1) The first equality is false. 2) What is the product in $(v - w)(v+w)$? For a correct reasoning, use the fact that the inner product is linear in each argument separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

True
Proof: 
$$
\begin{align*}
\langle v-w, v+w\rangle &= \langle v,v+w\rangle-\langle w,v+w\rangle \\
&=\langle v,v\rangle +\langle v,w\rangle-\langle w,v\rangle-\langle w,w\rangle\\
&=\langle v,v\rangle-\langle w,w\rangle\\
&=\|v\|_2^2 - \|w\|_2^2
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: I edited for formatting; take a look at the source if you'd like to see how I did it.

Comment: Ok I understood everything in your answer, how you formed it. The only thing I still don't understand is the beginning, how do you know that $$\left \langle v-w,v+w \right \rangle=\left \langle v,v+w \right \rangle-\left \langle w,v+w \right \rangle$$?

Comment: @tenepolis It is by distributivity of scalar product

Comment: @porton The property is actually the (bi)linearity property of the inner product. Though, depending on notation, it might look like distributivity.